# How to change the method name of a form using javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, radio-button

I am new to javascript. I have a form like this

```
<form id="frmid" action="index.php" method="get">    
    <label>Method</label>
    <input type="radio" name="typeMethod" value="POST" id="rdPost" checked="checked"  onchange="updatemethod()"/>
    <label for="rdPost">POST</label>
    <input type="radio" name="typeMethod" value="GET" id="rdGET" onchange="updatemethod()" />
    <label for="rdGET">GET</label>    
    <input type="text" name="firstName" value="" id="txtFirst" />    
    <input type="text" name="middleName" value="" id="txtMiddle" />
    <input type="text" name="lastName" value="" id="txtLast" />    
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="txtSubmit" value="Send Information" />       
</form>
```

I have a html form with the radio button. I am trying to write a javascript function `updatemethod()` where when I select a radio button it changes based on the radio button. 
I have done this

```
function updatemethod() {
    get = document.getElementById("rdGet");
    post = document.getElementById("rdPost");

    if (get.isChecked) {
        get.setAttribute("method", "GET");
    } else {
        post.setAttribute("method", "POST");
    }
}
```

I try to do but it is not working. 
Can somebody help me out

Comment: please show us your updatemethod function on javascript and console log javascript error. there might be a more clue in there.

Comment: As paul said u mixed something up, u set it to ur radio input

Answer (score 4):

You are setting the attribute on the radio button. Instead set it on the form.

A minimum change solution might look like.

```
function updatemethod() {
    const getBtn = document.getElementById("rdGet");
    const postBtn = document.getElementById("rdPost");

    if (getBtn.checked) {
        document.getElementById("frmid").setAttribute("method", "GET");
    } 
    else if (postBtn.checked) {
        document.getElementById("frmid").setAttribute("method", "POST");
    }            
}
```

If you inspect the element in the browsers developer tools, you can see the method change as you click the radio buttons.

There is another more concise way of doing this by calling the function and passing `this`.

```
onchange="updatemethod(this)"
```

Here `this` refers to the radio button element and now you don't need to do any DOM tree searches.

The function is now

```
function updatemethod(elem) {    
    if (elem.checked) {
        elem.form.setAttribute("method", elem.value);
    }      
}
```

This is however dependent on you having a appropriate `value` attribute in your html.

e.g.

```
<input type="radio"  value="VALID VALUE HERE" ... />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript DOM for this.

```
function updatemethod() {

    let formfrmId = document.getElementById('frmid');
    let typeMethod = document.getElementsByName('typeMethod');
    let numberRadioTypeMethod = typeMethod.length;

    for (i = 0; i < numberRadioTypeMethod; i++ ) {
        if (typeMethod[i].checked) 
            formfrmId.method = typeMethod[i].value;
    }
}
```

Use the browser console, it will give you all the DOM properties and features for you to use in javascript.